# cel in a TableLayout doesn't "match_parent"

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm adding rows and cels to TableLayout programaticly having issue to make cells match the parent height though, 
Row set up:

```
row = TableRow(context)
row.layoutParams = 
   TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
   TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f)
row.layoutParams = params;
```

then I'm looping trough some values and adding cells to "row" more or less like this:

```
for(i..7){
  val cel = TextView(context)
  val params = 
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
  cel.layoutParams =params
  cel.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
  cel.text = i.toString()
}
```

but the cel (TextView-in my case) does not fill up the height, tryed as well :

```
val params = 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f)
```

but did not work -in both cases table "disapears" totaly form the view when trying to set up layout params that way... anyone know maybe the correct aproach?

Comment: I don't see you adding cells to rows and rows to table. Are you doing that?

Comment: @EugenPechanec I did not added that to the question  beacuse didn't want to make a question too long but it's all there in my code:) and the whole table is displayed correcly untill I try to change layoutParams for a cell then everything disapears:S (ilet me know if You want to see how I add cells and rows then I will added to a question)

Comment: Ok, start by specifying the layout params correctly. Layout params are managed by parent view. So a `TableRow` should have `TableLayout.LayoutParams`, and whatever is a cell (here `TextView`) should have `TableRow.LayoutParams`. `TableLayout` tells `TableRow`s how to layout and `TableRow`s tell their cells how to layout. Understand?

Comment: @EugenPechanec you are a savior, it works -thank you alot for explanation sir- now I understand the logic behind it as well (y) (don't know why , but can only vote up your answer but can not mark as a correct answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by specifying the layout params correctly. **Layout params are managed by parent view.** So a `TableRow` should have `TableLayout.LayoutParams`, and whatever is a cell (here `TextView`) should have `TableRow.LayoutParams`. `TableLayout` tells `TableRows` how to layout and `TableRows` tell their cells how to layout.

All mentioned layout params (including `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`) take three arguments: width, height, and weight. When you use correct classes it should just work™.